# GitHub Actions build fails because of the token

Tags: android, xml, continuous-integration, github-actions

I've set up a new GitHub Actions workflow and builds are failing. The reason is that in the manifest file, I have a reference.

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
   android:value="@string/application_ad_id" />
```

The "@string/application_ad_id" is in a separate, git-ignored file. Switching to GitHub Secrets, I've created one and put an environment variable inside the .yml file.

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    env:
      APPLICATION_ADS_ID: ${{ secrets.APPLICATION_ADS_ID }}
      
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: gradle

    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
```

Now I need to point the manifest out to this secret variable. How do I do this? Or did I mess everything up and there's an easier way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the line like below in your manifest file,

```
android:value="@string/application_ad_id"
```

You can then have a step in your GitHub Actions workflow that replaces the manifest file (only during the workflow. wont commit the changes to the repo).

Like,

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      APPLICATION_ADS_ID: ${{ secrets.APPLICATION_ADS_ID }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Add the secret to the manifest file
      uses: MathieuSoysal/replace-string-in-file@v1.0.0
      with:
        file: <path to your manifest file>
        old-string: 'application_ad_id'
        new-string: ${{ env.APPLICATION_ADS_ID }}
```

So this way, you can replace the text `@string/application_ad_id` with the `APPLICATION_ADS_ID` environment variable (which is read from the GitHub secrets).

Comment: @Corec can you confirm whether this works?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! When I tried to use it with the `old-string: @string/application_ad_id`, it gave me a syntax error. I had to replace it with `old-string: "@string/application_ad_id"`. However, this option gave me a different error: `sed -i 's/@string/application_ad_id/***/g' app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` `sed: -e expression #1, char 29: unknown option to s'`. Sorry for the formatting, it's not simple to describe a multiline error in a comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: Hey Robin, since the "@" sign means that this is a string reference, I can't actually remove it. Otherwise, it becomes a plain string. I need a reference to the API token.

Comment: @Corec Had a chance to check out my updated answer and see if it works for you?